# How to fix 'events.js:174 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^ TypeError: respond is not a function'

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade angular 2 to latest version. I am done with all procedure in package json but the problem with the older node version.

I am getting this error.

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: respond is not a function
```

My Code :

```
UserSchema
    .path('email')
    .validate(function (value, respond) {
        var self = this;
      something.findOne({ email: value }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            if (user) {
             // something
                return respond(false);
            }
            respond(true);
        });
    }, 'Email Already Exists');
```

Comment: I had the same problem a couple minutes ago. The problem for me was that I had more than 1 terminal running in VScode that tried to run the command 'npm start'. So make sure to check that there is only 1 terminal running and let only that terminal run the command 'npm start'. Normally this shud fixes the problem.